# How to add mat-options to mat-select without reloading the page at the press of a button. Angular

Tags: angular, forms, append

Actually it is not at the press of a button it is when selecting another select, it returns by an internal process an array that I want to show in a new select in its options.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Rutas disponibles</mat-label>
    <mat-select id="select1">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let mv of moveByDoc" [value]="mv.id">
        {{mv.originpath}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

When loading the page, this select appears empty because "moveByDoc" is still empty, then when clicking on another select it would be filled and when it was filled in, I would like it to automatically load the options of this one, or to refresh only this select.

The ts code, the append does not work, does not add anything:

```
loadPath(idDoc){
   this.authService.getmoveByDoc(idDoc)
  .subscribe((res : getmovemodel[])=>{
    this.moveByDoc = res;

  }); 
}
```

IT ALREADY WORKS, I EDIT IT CORRECTLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="moveByDoc">
     <mat-label>Rutas disponibles</mat-label>
     <mat-select id="select1">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let mv of moveByDoc" [value]="mv.id">
        {{mv.originpath}}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and remove unnecessary code from loadPath :

```
loadPath(idDoc){
  this.authService.getmoveByDoc(idDoc)
  .subscribe((res : getmovemodel[])=>{
      this.moveByDoc = res; 
  });
}
```

Comment: loadPath must be called on ngOnInit, to see the options, after loading the page.